# AppEngine Deploy is Conflicting SHA1 sum for a file

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I want to deploy an update to our app but we have an issue with `gcloud` command which failed to "Conflicting SHA1 sum for file". Here is the output:

```
➜ gcloud app deploy xxx-xxx-xxxx.yaml --project xxx-xxx-xxxx --quiet 

Services to deploy:

descriptor:      [/home/vzool/Workspace/xxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx/xxx-xxx-xxxx.yaml]
source:          [/home/vzool/Workspace/xxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx]
target project:  [xxx-xxx-xxxx]
target service:  [default]
target version:  [20180917t110153]
target url:      [https://xxx-xxx-xxxx.appspot.com]


Beginning deployment of service [default]...
╔════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
╠═ Uploading 1 file to Google Cloud Storage                 ═╣
╚════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
File upload done.
Updating service [default]...failed.                                                                                                                                                                              
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [3] The following errors occurred while copying files to App Engine:
File https://storage.googleapis.com/staging.xxx-xxx-xxxx.appspot.com/c819d7599ceb31df8d4370eed1981defcb5034c6 failed with: Conflicting SHA1 sum for file. Expected "ddb6af3b_cf4bff57_613fb78d_208480fa_1717b3c4" but received "c819d759_9ceb31df_8d4370ee_d1981def_cb5034c6".

Details: [
  [
    {
      "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ResourceInfo",
      "description": "Conflicting SHA1 sum for file. Expected \"ddb6af3b_cf4bff57_613fb78d_208480fa_1717b3c4\" but received \"c819d759_9ceb31df_8d4370ee_d1981def_cb5034c6\".",
      "resourceName": "https://storage.googleapis.com/staging.xxx-xxx-xxxx.appspot.com/c819d7599ceb31df8d4370eed1981defcb5034c6",
      "resourceType": "file"
    }
  ]
]
```

I do delete this file `c819d7599ceb31df8d4370eed1981defcb5034c6` but everytime new hash will be generated, delete entire block `staging.xxx-xxx-xxxx.appspot.com` and I did clear `Memcache` but with no luck trying all these options! :(

I don't know what to do anymore with this, any suggestions may help me out?

Thanks

Comment: If you are still getting this error, please file a bug in [Issue Tracker] (https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers). As a potential workaround, delete the bucket staging.{Your-Project-ID}.appspot.com located under storage since it will remove any temporary files that might cause this error.

Comment: @David Thanks for your care, I found the solution <3

Comment: Have the same issue and this answer works for me:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/52894113/8244338

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think after sometime in research the issue, the app itself has a live feature which lead to update one file while you open live page.
So, that change what `gcloud` uploaded.
`gcloud` upload then verify. And if file changed after upload and before verify `gcloud` will through this error on your face. Ha ha ha ^_^

Comment: But how I can stop that feature? I don't see any

Answer (score 0):

OP's answer seemed to indicate that a file got touched during the `gcloud` deploy process.

The solution for me was to:

1. `git checkout` some random branch
2. `git checkout` the branch I was actually trying to deploy again
3. run `gcloud app deploy .  --version my_version_id --project my_project_id`