# ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [3] The following errors occurred while copying files to App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, gcloud

Getting this error when I try to deploy to google app engine:
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [3] The following errors occurred while copying files to App Engine:

```
File https://storage.googleapis.com/staging.XXXXXXXX.appspot.com/04314f892fba4e2f44a86ab96eeb2a6b72ed93cd failed with: Conflicting SHA1 sum for file. Expected "6ae2b40e_68bc1a25_8cc5408c_bbd37316_fa642477" but received "04314f89_2fba4e2f_44a86ab9_6eeb2a6b_72ed93cd".
File https://storage.googleapis.com/staging.XXXXXXXX.appspot.com/d06cfbf61df973ee19498c5a6d8afd5c3f971cb1 failed with: Conflicting SHA1 sum for file. Expected "cf32ec49_c6023a31_6d3f4788_f187afcb_932d60df" but received "d06cfbf6_1df973ee_19498c5a_6d8afd5c_3f971cb1".

Details: [
  [
    {
      "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ResourceInfo",
      "description": "Conflicting SHA1 sum for file. Expected \"6ae2b40e_68bc1a25_8cc5408c_bbd37316_fa642477\" but received \"04314f89_2fba4e2f_44a86ab9_6eeb2a6b_72ed93cd\".",
      "resourceName": "https://storage.googleapis.com/staging.XXXXXXXX.appspot.com/04314f892fba4e2f44a86ab96eeb2a6b72ed93cd",
      "resourceType": "file"
    },
    {
      "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ResourceInfo",
      "description": "Conflicting SHA1 sum for file. Expected \"cf32ec49_c6023a31_6d3f4788_f187afcb_932d60df\" but received \"d06cfbf6_1df973ee_19498c5a_6d8afd5c_3f971cb1\".",
      "resourceName": "https://storage.googleapis.com/staging.XXXXXXXX.appspot.com/d06cfbf61df973ee19498c5a6d8afd5c3f971cb1",
      "resourceType": "file"
    }
  ]
]
```

Comment: is it possible that you might be trying to deploy files with code that are larger than 32 mb? - https://cloud.google.com/appengine/quotas#Code Also, a workaround for this situation might be deleting the bucket staging.{Your-Project-ID}.appspot.com located under storage since it will remove any temporary files that might cause this error.

Comment: Thanks @PhilippSh, deleting the staging bucket worked for me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An appropriate workaround for this situation might be deleting the bucket staging.{Your-Project-ID}.appspot.com located under storage since it will remove any temporary files that might cause this error.

Comment: I cleared all the contents in the staging.{project-id}.appspot.com bucket. But still failing.

Answer (score 0):

The error could be caused by temporary files appeared in your app after build. (e.g. for flutter apps you may find unexpected *.cache.dill files)