# gcloud app deploy triggers weird error: Conflicting SHA1 sum for file

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I am trying to get a simple HelloWorld! deployment setup to AppEngine. I'm working with another friend/developer, who on his machine was able to get this simple `gcloud app deploy` to work successfully, but on my machine it is not working (classic *works on my machine*). I'm wondering if it's a permission issue with our buckets, but everything between me and my friend's AppEngine accounts are mirrored. I'm at my wit's and so any help is appreciated.

What I will describe to follow seems to be a rare find on the internet so I'm hopeful that someone knowledgeable can help.

- I have the GoogleCloudSDK installed and authenticated.
- I have a simple directory named "default" with an app.yaml and an index.html

When running the `gcloud app deploy default` command I receive the following error:

```
Beginning deployment of service [default]...
╔═════════════════════════════════════════════╗
╠═ Uploading 2 files to Google Cloud Storage ═╣
╚═════════════════════════════════════════════╝
File upload done.
Updating service [default]...failed.
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [3] The following errors occurred while copying files to App Engine:
File https://storage.googleapis.com/staging.xxxxxxx.appspot.com/59add2715212c2a5fa68f05ead6ea6a307d279b5 failed with: Conflicting SHA1 sum for file. Expected "90d147b8_dd2137ab_8ec7f19f_c0891006_6585d3de" but received "59add271_5212c2a5_fa68f05e_ad6ea6a3_07d279b5".

Details: [
  [
    {
      "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ResourceInfo",
      "description": "Conflicting SHA1 sum for file. Expected \"90d147b8_dd2137ab_8ec7f19f_c0891006_6585d3de\" but received \"59add271_5212c2a5_fa68f05e_ad6ea6a3_07d279b5\".",
      "resourceName": "https://storage.googleapis.com/staging.xxxxxxx.appspot.com/59add2715212c2a5fa68f05ead6ea6a307d279b5",
      "resourceType": "file"
    }
  ]
]
```

### What I have tried

- Deleting all of the files within the bucket.
- Deleting the entire bucket at staging.xxxxxxx.appspot.com.
- Uninstalling and reinstalling the SDK from https://cloud.google.com/sdk/. I'm on Windows 10 64bit.
- Re-running `gcloud init` and going through those instructions.
- Re-running `gcloud auth application-default login` and authenticating with my Google account.

### Here are my example files

**app.yaml**

```yaml
runtime: nodejs10

handlers:
- url: /
  static_files: index.html
  upload: index.html
```

**index.html**

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test Title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>
      Hello from the static index.html file.
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I also encounter this issue about 50% of the time when I run `gcloud app deploy`, I have to run the command between 1 and 5 times for it to succesfully deploy. I have the feeling it might be due to an instable internet connection, but I am not sure

Comment: It appears you filed this issue on Google's public Issue Tracker. Did you receive any out-of-band responses to your issue? Or was it just closed? https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/122326194

Comment: You can compute the sha1sums yourself for your files to further determine where the issue is occurring. I'm using linux and there's `sha1sum <file>` but it appears you may be able to use FCIV on WIndows: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/889768/how-to-compute-the-md5-or-sha-1-cryptographic-hash-values-for-a-file

Comment: It would be interesting to know whether this issue only arises on Windows (@sven-hakvoort -- are you Windows too?). Could it be that Windows files CR+LR are getting converted (somehow) to Linux LF in some files and this is causing the hashes to not match?

Comment: @DazWilkin, yes I am also using windows when this issue occurs, so that could be of influence

Comment: I tried fudging the files to include carriage returns (`\r`) to see whether that was an issue but it appears to not affect the behavior. I'm unable to repro your error on Linux. If I find time, I'll try with Windows.

Comment: The argument to the command should be one or more yaml files, has explaining the documentation, https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/app/deploy, not the name of the directory where these files and the application’s are.

Answer (score 0):

Summary of the issue:
Different size of the text files on the Windows local machine file system and in the Google Cloud Storage - failed SHA checksum compare.

Possible solutions:

> 1. Fix files locally before deploying app using [Dos2Unix](http://dos2unix.sourceforge.net/) using Cigwin,

or deploy from Linux:

> 2. Upload deployment files to [Cloud Shell](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/using-the-session-window#using_the_code_editor) and deploy from there.
> 3. Upload deployment files to [Linux VM Instance](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/transfer-files#transferbrowser).

For summary of [Windows and Unix interoperability](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/Filenameencodingandinteroperabilityproblems), check documentation

Answer (score 0):

Use the old method for deploy - appcfg.py:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/appcfg-arguments

Works for me.

Or you can see this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/52894113/8244338